# How can i recover "Ubuntu" or "Ubuntu 2D" sessions?

Tags: 12.04, session, unity-greeter

I'm using **Ubuntu 12.04 lts**. When I upgrade from **11.04** i've got some Errors with `nautilus`. Yesterday I uninstall `nautilus` and reinstall it. I made the last system update (with a `unity-greeter` update). Since then I can't not see **Ubuntu** nor **Ubuntu 2D** Sessions... I can use kde desktop.

What is the problem right now?

Thank you for helping.

**Edit 1:** I remark that into `/usr/share/xsessions` `ubuntu-2d.desktop` and `ubuntu.desktop` dont exist...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just install the package "ubuntu-desktop". It contains everything that's contained in the standard installation.